# SAS iterpolation : alternative to proc expand

Tags: sas

From annual data :

[image]

I would like to create the the data per day but I can't use the proc expand because the SAS ETS is not available.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: From annually to daily? Any seasonality or other supporting data?

Comment: Not ideal, but I'd consider a linear regression - please post data as text not as images. Don't want to type out your data to generate any code.

Comment: @Reeza non, I have just this data.

Comment: Normally, it's a linear regression. Unfortunately, I don't know how to add the data to my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is a basic approach perhaps:

- create a list of dates for interpolation
- merge have data (shown above, not included in code below)
- Plot to see if linear pattern, (looks somewhat exponential/curved)
- run linear regression, saving predicted values
- plot interpolated values against actual values

```
data years;
do date='30Jun2017'd to '30Jun2022'd;
output;
end;
run;



data have;
merge years have;
by date;
format date date9.;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
series x=date y=px_last;
run;

proc reg data=have plots;
model px_last = date;
output out=pred p=predicted_value;
run;

proc sgplot data=pred;
series x=date y=predicted_Value;
scatter x=date y=px_last;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Reeza. I have a question, for exemple, in PREDICT table, the observation of 30/06/2017 (in input 541,098313884774) is replaced by (522,228952915977). I thought that Predict data will hold the 541,098313884774, the input observation.

Comment: No, a regression doesn't get forced through the data points.

Comment: thank you! Do I need to replace this point by the real observation?

Comment: You can, but you may have a weird blip in your data then, as the points on either side (days) will not align.